# restoring /lib64/libperl.so on CentOS

Tags: centos, package-management

I have deleted `/lib64/libperl.so`, by mistake, on my CentOS release 6.8 (Final).

How do I restore this library? I have tried to search for a package name that may contain this file but could not find anything.

Comment: Search again but harder. It may was only a symbolic link.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell yum to install single files. It will take longer to get started since it must now download the much larger filelists from the repositories, but it will get the job done.

```
yum reinstall /lib64/libperl.so
```